# React.JS как сделать вывод текста без разрыва слов

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть приложение на React.JS, в нём div в который выводится текст из базы данных. но есть проблема, если текст не влазит в строку, то слово разрывается и одна, часть на одной строке, другая на другой. Как это решить? Что бы слово или осталось на этой строке, или перенеслось на следующую. Пробовал разбирать строку на массив, после чего добавлять к каждой строке в массиве тег с классом, но React.JS не рендерит html элементы, как элементы. Он рендерит их как текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

см. подробнее: http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/02/word-wrap.html

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, очень помогли.